# VPN does not reconnect (cannot resolve host address)

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables

maybe someone can help me:

At the moment i am trying to configure a fail-safe VPN connection to a commercial VPN provider on a virtual machine. This is working fine, until my router wants to reset my IPv4 puplic address (every few days). Then the VPN client on the VM can not reconnect to the VPN server, because it cannot connect to a DNS server, cause of my iptables settings (just my assumption).

My Setup:

The VM has a virtual IP address in my local network. On the VM there is a proxy server running (squid). So all my clients (on my local netwok) applications can use the VPN connection on the VM to access the internet.

I am using Debian 7.8 with openvpn 2.2.1-8+deb7u3, squid 2.7.STABLE9-4.1+deb7u1 and iptables 1.4.14-3.1 on my VM.

Configs:

openvpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote urlofvpnserver.com 3478
cipher AES-128-CBC
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca TrustedRoot.pem
verb 3
auth-user-pass /root/.secretfile
reneg-sec 0
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
```

iptables:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [6:1984]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [177:11271]
```

//local communication
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

//accept local network traffic
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT

//allow connections to the VPN servers different IP ranges
-A OUTPUT -d ***hiddenvpnwebsite*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ***hidden*** -j ACCEPT

//squid port
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT

//DNS servers
-A INPUT -s 208.67.222.222/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 208.67.222.222/32 -j ACCEPT

//allow traffic on tun
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

//open openvpn ports
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.122
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 8.8.8.8
        dns-search 208.67.222.222
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

/var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

```
Wed Jan 28 03:59:46 2015 OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
Wed Jan 28 03:59:46 2015 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Jan 28 03:59:46 2015 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Wed Jan 28 03:59:46 2015 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1557 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Jan 28 03:59:46 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[229376->131072] S=[229376->131072]
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1557 D:1450 EF:57 EB:4 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '8326dbaa'
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'b7f67de4'
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]one_of_the_hidden_vpn_ips:3478
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]one_of_the_hidden_vpn_ips:3478, sid=68e25514 fb7384de
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=2, hidden_CA
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, hidden_CA
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, hidden_CA .hidden_vpn_url
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 4096 bit RSA
Wed Jan 28 03:59:47 2015 [_.hidden_vpn_url] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]hidden_vpn_ip:3478
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 SENT CONTROL [_.hidden_vpn_url]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220,topology subnet,ping 5,ping-restart 15,explicit-exit-notify,route-gateway 10.3.$
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.2.1
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.3.134.57 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 broadcast 10.3.134.255
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 /sbin/route add -net hidden_vpn_ip netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.2.1
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 /sbin/route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 10.3.134.57
Wed Jan 28 03:59:49 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: now everything works, until my router disconnects:

Wed Jan 28 05:33:48 2015 [_.***hidden_vpn_url***] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Jan 28 05:33:48 2015 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Wed Jan 28 05:33:48 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Wed Jan 28 05:33:48 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Wed Jan 28 05:33:50 2015 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Jan 28 05:33:50 2015 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Wed Jan 28 05:33:50 2015 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Wed Jan 28 05:33:50 2015 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1557 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Jan 28 05:33:50 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[229376->131072] S=[229376->131072]
Wed Jan 28 05:35:10 2015 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: ***hidden_vpn_url***: [HOST_NOT_FOUND] The specified host is unknown.
Wed Jan 28 05:35:10 2015 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1557 D:1450 EF:57 EB:4 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Jan 28 05:35:10 2015 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '8326dbaa'
Wed Jan 28 05:35:10 2015 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'b7f67de4'
Wed Jan 28 05:36:30 2015 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address:  ***hidden_vpn_url***: [HOST_NOT_FOUND] The specified host is unknown.
Wed Jan 28 05:37:55 2015 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address:  ***hidden_vpn_url***: [HOST_NOT_FOUND] The specified host is unknown.
Wed Jan 28 05:39:20 2015 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address:  ***hidden_vpn_url***: [HOST_NOT_FOUND] The specified host is unknown.
Wed Jan 28 05:40:45 2015 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address:  ***hidden_vpn_url***: [HOST_NOT_FOUND] The specified host is unknown.

I assume the problem is the following:
In the openvpn config i have to set the url of the vpn provider instead of a ip address with: remote urlofvpnserver.com 3478.

I tried to change this to an IP address of the vpn provider. But they use more then one IP address and range. I think on server side i will be connected to a server, wich is not that overloaded, to guarantee the best connection speed. But if i change ***urlofvpnserver.com*** to one of their IP addresses, connection only works 50% of the time. (some vpn server scripts may be blocking this)

So after i lost the connection to the vpn, the VM tries to resolve the IP address of ***urlofvpnserver.com*** by asking the DNS server. But the VM can not connect to the DNS server, because it maybe forced to use a VPN connection?

Sry for editing my config files. I am just a little paranoid. I just began learning iptables and network protocolls. So i may be totally wrong.

Anyone has an idea, how to fix this? So the VPN client can reconnect after router DC or internet connection problems? I'd be happy to provide more specific information if someone needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is a bug in openvpn with this, Had a similar problem and  solved it by creating a simple service which restarts openvpn service if there is no openvpn tunnel. Works fine for my needs, have no problem with the stability of the connection.

here is a sample script for the service.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  sleep 50
  if ifconfig | grep tun0;
  then
    echo tunnel is available
  else
    echo "no tunnel available , going to restart openvpn"
    systemctl restart "openvpn@client.service"
  fi
done
```